# How to snapshot and save a rendered Metal drawable in macOS Cocoa Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, metal

I've got an app that uses Metal to do some rendering to screen (with a `CAMetalLayer`, not a `MTKView`, by necessity), and I'd like to provide the user with the option of saving a snapshot of the result to disk.  Attempting to follow the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47632198/2752221 while translating to Objective-C, I first wrote a commandBuffer completion callback like so (note this is manual retain/release code, not ARC; sorry, legacy code):

```
[commandBuffer addCompletedHandler:^(id<MTLCommandBuffer> buffer) {
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(saveImageTakingDrawable:) withObject:[drawable retain] waitUntilDone:NO];
    optionKeyPressedAndUnhandled_ = NO;
}];
```

I do this immediately after calling `[commandBuffer presentDrawable:drawable]`; my `id <CAMetalDrawable> drawable` is still in scope.  Here is my implementation of `saveImageTakingDrawable:`:

```
- (void)saveImageTakingDrawable:(id <CAMetalDrawable>)drawable
{
    // We need to have an image to save
    if (!drawable) { NSBeep(); return; }

    id<MTLTexture> displayTexture = drawable.texture;

    if (!displayTexture) { NSBeep(); return; }

    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithMTLTexture:displayTexture options:nil];

    // release the metal texture as soon as we can, to free up the system resources
    [drawable release];

    if (!ciImage) { NSBeep(); return; }

    NSCIImageRep *rep = [NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:ciImage];

    if (!rep) { NSBeep(); return; }

    NSImage *nsImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:rep.size] autorelease];
    [nsImage addRepresentation:rep];

    NSData *tiffData = [nsImage TIFFRepresentation];

    if (!tiffData) { NSBeep(); return; }

    ... filesystem cruft culminating in ...

    if ([tiffData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingWithoutOverwriting error:nil])
    {
        // play a sound to acknowledge saving
        [[NSSound soundNamed:@"Tink"] play];
        return;
    }

    NSBeep();
    return;
}
```

The result is a "Tink" sound and a 7.8 MB .tif file of sensible dimensions (1784x1090), but it's transparent, and there is no usable image data in it; viewing the file in Hex Fiend shows that the whole file is all zeros except fairly brief header and footer sections.

I suspect that the fundamental method is flawed for some reason.  I get several console logs when I attempt this snapshot:

```
2020-06-04 18:20:40.203669-0400 MetalTest[37773:1065740] [CAMetalLayerDrawable texture] should not be called after already presenting this drawable. Get a nextDrawable instead.
Input Metal texture was created with a device that does not match the current context device.
Input Metal texture was created with a device that does not match the current context device.
2020-06-04 18:20:40.247637-0400 MetalTest[37773:1065740] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x600000297260> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2020-06-04 18:20:40.281161-0400 MetalTest[37773:1065740]  HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: Can't get a pointer to the Open routine
```

That first log seems to suggest that I'm really not even allowed to get the texture out of the drawable after it has been presented in the first place.  So... what's the right way to do this?

UPDATE:

Note that I am not wedded to the later parts of `saveImageTakingDrawable:`'s code.  I would be happy to write out a PNG instead of a TIFF, and if there's a way to get where I'm going without using `CIImage`, `NSCIImageRep`, or `NSImage`, so much the better.  I just want to save the drawable's texture image out as a PNG or TIFF, *somehow*.

Comment: Does SO allow me to tag @KenThomases?  I will try.  :->

Comment: Would it be possible to use NSTask and 'screencapture' code found in this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61731812/for-macos-cocoa-how-do-i-specify-a-window-or-a-rectangle-on-the-screen-for-taki/61739312?noredirect=1#comment109241081_61739312

Comment: For what it's worth, the tagging didn't work, but I found it anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to save the drawable's texture image out as a PNG or TIFF, somehow.

Here is an alternative approach which you may test; will need to set the path to wherever you want the image file saved.

```
- (void) windowCapture: (id)sender {
 NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc]init];
 [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh"]; 
 NSArray *args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"-c", @"screencapture -i -c -Jwindow", nil];
 [task setArguments:args]; 
 NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
 [task setStandardOutput:pipe]; 
 [task launch];
 [task waitUntilExit];
 int status = [task terminationStatus]; 
 NSData *dataRead = [[pipe fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile];
 NSString *pipeOutput = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataRead encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
 // Tell us if there was a problem
 if (!(status == 0)){NSLog(@"Error: %@",pipeOutput);}
 [task release];
 // Get image data from pasteboard and write to file
 NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
 NSData *pngData = [pboard dataForType:NSPasteboardTypePNG];
 NSError *err;
 BOOL success = [pngData writeToFile:@"/Users/xxxx/Desktop/ABCD.png" options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&err];
 if(!success){NSLog(@"Unable to write to file: %@",err);} else {NSLog(@"File written to desktop.");}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should inject a blit into the command buffer (before submitting it) to copy the texture to a texture of your own. (The drawable's texture is not safe to use after it has been presented, as you've found.)

One strategy is to set the layer's `framebufferOnly` to false for the pass, and then use a `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` to encode a copy from the drawable texture to a texture of your own. Or, if the pixel formats are different, encode a draw of a quad from the drawable texture to your own, using a render command encoder.

The other strategy is to substitute your own texture as the render target color attachment where your code is currently using the drawable's texture. Render to your texture primarily and then draw that to the drawable's texture.

Either way, your texture's `storageMode` can be `MTLStorageModeManaged`, so you can access its data with one of the `-getBytes:...` methods. You just have to make sure that the command buffer encodes a `synchronizeResource:` command of a blit encoder at the end.

You can then use the bytes to construct an `NSBitmapImageRep` using the `-initWithBitmapDataPlanes:pixelsWide:pixelsHigh:bitsPerSample:samplesPerPixel:hasAlpha:isPlanar:colorSpaceName:bitmapFormat:bytesPerRow:bitsPerPixel:` method. Then, get PNG data from it using `-representationUsingType:properties:` and save that to file.